# Safehouse to FTP location

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to transfer a file from Safehouse to an FTP location but without selecting the checkbox for Encrypt File Under Transfer Settings because I wanted to view the data in the file. When I run the import activity, I got a file not found error, but I am able to successfully import the data from Safehouse to DE.

Is there any option to transfer files from a safehouse to an FTP without encrypting them?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to transfer a file from Safehouse to the FTP location, you will have to use a `File Transfer` activity rather than an `Import File` activity. Encrypting the files is not a requirement, but rather an option.

I may need more details in order to recommend the best path forward.

1. Is the file a Tracking or Data Extract?
2. If the above is not true, where is the file coming from and how did it get to the Safehouse?
3. What file type is it?